# C++: What GNU G++ parameters?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, warnings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best compiler warning level for C/C++ compilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399850/best-compiler-warning-level-for-c-c-compilers)

GCC has thousands of options to add more warnings; I was hoping that `-Wall` `-Wextra` `-pedantic` included all the useful ones, but just now I met `-Woverloaded-virtual` which seems really nice to me.

What other G++ parameters do you use or would you recommend?

Comment: Maybe check the documentation?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399850/best-compiler-warning-level-for-c-c-compilers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite the same category but I always compile with `-Werror` to flag warnings as errors. Very useful.

To make this work with 3rd party headers, I include those headers via `-isystem` instead of `-I` … otherwise warnings in those headers will break the build.

There’s also `-Weffc++` which warns for specific issues outlined in Meyers’ *Effective C++*. However, I’ve found this too harsh. For example, it warns for base classes that don’t declare virtual destructors. In theory, this is very nice but I’m working on a template library that uses inheritance for code reuse (and policy classes) and obviously they don’t have (nor need) virtual destructors.

Comment: I agree that `-Weffc++` is too harsh. Once in a while, though, I compile with it to check my code.

Comment: Ironically, `-Weffc++` warns about deriving from the policy class `boost::noncopyable`, but iheriting from such a class is recommended by Effective C++. Similarly, it warns about inheriting `std::unary_function` and friends. GCC should be a bit more smart here: a class without data members and without public member functions is unlikely to be used polymorphically.

Comment: @Philipp: The issues are known and there are several filed bugs and discussions on the GCC mailing list about that … I don’t see this being fixed soon, though.

Answer (score 1):

Some that I've seen that are used;

> `-Wcast-qual`: Warn whenever a pointer is cast so as to remove a type qualifier from the target type.  For example, warn if a `const char *` is cast to an ordinary `char *`.
>
> `-Wpointer-arith`: Warn about anything that depends on the size of a function type or of `void`. GNU C assigns these types a size of 1, for convenience in calculations with `void *` pointers and pointers to functions.
>
> `-Wwrite-strings`: When compiling C, give string constants the type `const char[length]` so that copying the address of one into a non-`const` `char *` pointer will get a warning; when compiling C++, warn about the deprecated conversion from string literals to `char *`.  This warning, by default, is enabled for C++ programs. These warnings will help you find at compile time code that can try to write into a string constant, but only if you have been very careful about using `const` in declarations and prototypes. Otherwise, it will just be a nuisance; this is why we did not make -Wall request these warnings.
>
> `-Wdisabled-optimization`: Warn if a requested optimization pass is disabled. This warning does not generally indicate that there is anything wrong with your code; it merely indicates that GCC's optimizers were unable to handle the code effectively. Often, the problem is that your code is too big or too complex; GCC will refuse to optimize programs when the optimization itself is likely to take inordinate amounts of time.

Answer (score 1):

See [Best compiler warning level for C/C++ compilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399850/best-compiler-warning-level-for-c-c-compilers). One post contains the following exhaustive (and exhausting) list.

```
   -g -O -Wall -Weffc++ -pedantic  \
    -pedantic-errors -Wextra  -Wall -Waggregate-return -Wcast-align \
    -Wcast-qual  -Wchar-subscripts  -Wcomment -Wconversion \
    -Wdisabled-optimization \
    -Werror -Wfloat-equal  -Wformat  -Wformat=2 \
    -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security  \
    -Wformat-y2k \
    -Wimplicit  -Wimport  -Winit-self  -Winline \
    -Winvalid-pch   \
    -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations  -Wlong-long -Wmissing-braces \
    -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wmissing-format-attribute   \
    -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wmissing-noreturn \
    -Wpacked  -Wpadded -Wparentheses  -Wpointer-arith \
    -Wredundant-decls -Wreturn-type \
    -Wsequence-point  -Wshadow -Wsign-compare  -Wstack-protector \
    -Wstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -Wswitch  -Wswitch-default \
    -Wswitch-enum -Wtrigraphs  -Wuninitialized \
    -Wunknown-pragmas  -Wunreachable-code -Wunused \
    -Wunused-function  -Wunused-label  -Wunused-parameter \
    -Wunused-value  -Wunused-variable  -Wvariadic-macros \
    -Wvolatile-register-var  -Wwrite-strings
```

Comment: Some of those are redundant. For example, the second `-Wall` and the `-Wcomment` are both implied by the first `-Wall`. `-Werror` + `-pedantic` implies `-pedantic-errors`.

Comment: Indeed. In any case, it's overkill. But it's a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

In general I enable all warnings and then remove those flags selectively that give useless outputs. In one of my projects, I use the following C and C++ warnings:

```
-pedantic
-Wall
-Wextra
-Wformat=2
-Wmissing-include-dirs
-Wswitch-default
-Wswitch-enum
-Wunused
-Wstrict-aliasing=1
-Wfloat-equal
-Wundef
-Wunsafe-loop-optimizations
-Wpointer-arith
-Wcast-qual
-Wcast-align
-Wwrite-strings
-Wconversion
-Wmissing-format-attribute
-Wpacked
-Wredundant-decls
-Winvalid-pch
-Wvolatile-register-var
-Wsync-nand
-Wsign-conversion
-Wlogical-op
-Wmissing-declarations
-Wmissing-noreturn
-Wstrict-overflow=5
-Wstack-protector
```

In addition, I use the following C++ flags:

```
-std=c++98
-Wnon-virtual-dtor
-Wctor-dtor-privacy
-Wstrict-null-sentinel
-Woverloaded-virtual
-Wsign-promo
```

In addition, for the release build I enable the following warnings:

```
-pedantic-errors
-Werror
-Wuninitialized
-Winit-self
-Wdisabled-optimization
```

I find it quite annoying that `-Wall` enables only the absolute minimum of warnings instead of "all", as the name implies.

Comment: I would have thought that `-Wdisabled-optimization -Werror` is a bit brave in release mode. Reject any code that's not suitable for *all* optimizations. Or is it a trick to enforce small functions? ;-)

Comment: @Steve Jessop: For that project (which is very small) it works, but for other projects I'd disable that flag if it caused warnings. Also, `-Wswitch-enum` can become quite annoying for large enums.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the ones already mentioned above:

```
-pedantic                   Issue warnings needed for strict compliance to the standard
-Wall
-Wextra                     Print extra (possibly unwanted) warnings
-Werror                     Treat all warnings as errors
-std=c++0x                  Conform to the ISO 1998 C++ standard, with extensions that are likely to be in C++0x 
-std=c++98                  Conform to the ISO 1998 C++ standard
```