# Recommended -W flags for building C++ with gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, build-process, compiler-warnings

I was looking for a list of recommended g++ warning options for C++ and only could find this: [Recommended gcc warning options for C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154630/recommended-gcc-warning-options-for-c) and [Useful GCC flags for C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375697/useful-gcc-flags-for-c) which are all quite C specific

-Wall and -Wextra enable most but not all of the warnings gcc can generate.

Which warnings that aren't enabled by those options especially when compiling C++ should be turned on as well?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661561/c-what-gnu-g-parameters

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`-Wall -Wextra` tends to cover the really noteworthy ones. Personally, I also like to compile with `-ansi -pedantic` and occasionally `-Wshadow`.

Also, it can be a little noisy and not useful 100% of the time, but `-Weffc++` sometimes has good suggestions for better code quality as well.

**EDIT** In the age of modern C++, you should replace `-ansi -pedantic` with `-std=c++14 -pedantic` or whatever your version of choice is, since `-ansi` will put the compiler into C++98/C++-03 mode.

Comment: Never knew about effc++. Looks interesting.

Comment: @pmr you should get the books too!

Comment: @stefan What makes you think I don't already have them? It's just the compiler switch that surprised me :)

Comment: @pmr Awesome books none the less.

Comment: Unfortunately, -Weffc++ is not well designed/maintained and it reports too much useless stuff. Sadly, I had to disable it.

Comment: @Offirmo: yea, I agree, that's why i said that it can be noisy and not always useful.

Comment: @Offirmo do you have specific complaints in mind? It may be possible to improve the warning (I'm not yet volunteering, just trying to understand the opportunities). I've personally been hit by "XXX should be initialized in the member initialization list" for detaul-initialized members which is plain silly.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget `-Wstrict-aliasing`.

I found this post was good, look the params up:
[Recommended gcc warning options for C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154630/recommended-gcc-warning-options-for-c/415171#415171)

Comment: -Wstrict-aliasing is included in -Wall

Comment: @lefticus cool! i didnt know that. either is a "new" addition or i've just been blind, cool!