# How do I get g++ to compile c++11 code with a move constructor?

Tags: c++, g++, c++11, move-constructor

I can't seem to get g++ to compile c++11 code that uses a move constructor. I keep getting this error:

```
collin@Serenity:~/Projects/arraylib$ g++ ./t2.cpp
./t2.cpp:10:27: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&&’ token
./t2.cpp:10:38: error: invalid constructor; you probably meant ‘Blarg (const Blarg&)’
```

The program I am writing is quite different from this, but I trimmed it down to the part that seems like it should definitely work, yet still triggers the error:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Blarg {
    public:
        Blarg () {};
        Blarg (const Blarg& original) {}; /* Copy constructor */
        Blarg (Blarg&& original) {}; /* Move constructor */
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Blarg b;
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Rather, how to fix it?

This is my gcc version:

```
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.2-14ubuntu2) 4.6.2
```

Comment: Note that passing a const reference for a move constructor is pretty useless; realistically that should be `Blarg(Blarg&& original)`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I've fixed that in my actual code. I'll fix it above, too.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Say `g++ -std=c++0x ./t2.cpp`.

While you're at it, you might as well Do It Right and enable all warnings:

```
g++ -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++0x -o t2 t2.cpp
```

You really, really shouldn't be compiling with any less, *especially* if you are going to ask questions about your code on SO :-) Various optimization flags should optionally be considered for the release version, such as `-s -O2 -flto -march=native`.

Comment: "Do It Right", while the man page for -std=c++0x states "This option enables experimental features that may be removed in future" They sure are defensive in those manpages :-)

Comment: Thanks so much for saving me from filtering through the 600+ page manual... I'll just double check that this works the way I intended and then mark this as the answer.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: To be sure, the dialect option isn't subsumed under "doing it right". That said, `c++0x` will be supported for some time, but from 4.7 onward you can say `c++11`, too.

Comment: Ooh, can't wait to put that switch into action. Christmas parcels comes early this year=)

Comment: Unfortunately, even `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` doesn't enable _all_ warnings (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661561 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399850)

Comment: @Philipp That's fortunate, not unfortunate. For an extreme example: do you really want a warning for *every* variable you declare, ever, anywhere in your program, even the ones implicitly generated by the compiler? (`-Wlarger-than=1`) For a less extreme example: do you really want a warning when you use, for instance, `long long`, when you already specify `-std=c++11` on the command-line to enable new C++11 language features such as that one? (`-Wlong-long`)

Answer (score 15):

You probably forgot to add `-std=c++0x` to your commandline.

Comment: Poor thing, same answer time with just as good relevant answer but not as many up votes. I think yours is a more succinct relevant answer!