# Ultra pedantic compilation

Tags: c++11, g++, clang++

I’ve been wondering for the past few days whether it’s possible to make `g++` and `clang++` more pedantic than with `-std=c++11 -w -pedantic`.

Especially, I’d like these behaviors:

- when replacing a virtual method, `g++` and `clang++` have to raise an error if the `override` keyword is not present in the prototype of the replaced method (I think it’s a warning for now);
- all methods must have exception hint (`noexcept` or whatever), because it’s quite important, especially for ctor / dtor;
- I’m also looking for any other pedantic features you’d have in mind.

Comment: For the first bullet point, isn't that just a matter of using `-Werror` to convert warnings into errors?

Comment: it is, but it’s too general: it applies to all warnings. It’s a way to do it yeah but I’d like something more precise.

Comment: I believe you can use `-Werror=...` to convert specific warnings (although I don't know which warning missing overrides corresponds to, try perusing http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options).  But why *wouldn't* you want all warnings as errors?

Comment: because some warnings are not worth to be considered as errors imho, like the one that mentions unused variables

Comment: `noexcept` isn't as important as you seem to think.

Comment: Well I think it should be used because calling a function in a dtor that throws exception is error-prone

Comment: @phaazon: The thing is, with `noexcept` the function can still throw an exception, the compiler just guarantees that your program will be killed if it happens. It's a runtime check, not a compile time one.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors
```

Comment: I meant [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399850/best-compiler-warning-level-for-c-c-compilers), sorry.

Comment: does `clang++` also support that as well?

Comment: @phaazon Yes, it does.