# Setting platform-specific / compiler-specific target properties with CMake

Tags: c, visual-c++, cmake, compiler-options

I'm working on a C project whose `CMakeLists.txt` has the following:

```
set_property(
    TARGET foo
    APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_OPTIONS -Wall
)
```

This was fine as long as I could assume the compiler would be gcc or clang, which I was assuming. But - for MSVC, `-Wall` means [something else](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20433074/1593077) and undesirable, so I want to set other switches. How can I / how should I go about doing this?

Note: I'm not asking *which* compiler options to use, I'm asking *how* to apply my choices of flags (or any other property) using CMake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MSVC equivalent of gcc/clang's -Wall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568053/msvc-equivalent-of-gcc-clangs-wall)

Comment: @ChrisTurner: No, that question is about which compiler switches are appropriate; this question is about how to set different properties with CMake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modern way to set compiler flags in cross-platform cmake project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45955272/modern-way-to-set-compiler-flags-in-cross-platform-cmake-project)

Comment: @Florian: Not a dupe, since that question is mostly about setting up multiple builds for multiple compilers in the same directory (the third point out of three there, but being the most important).

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it might be something line:

```
if ("${CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "Clang")
  set_property(TARGET foo APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_OPTIONS -Wall)
elseif ("${CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")
  set_property(TARGET foo APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_OPTIONS -Wall)
elseif ("${CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "MSVC")
  set_property(TARGET foo APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_OPTIONS /W3)
```

and the list of compiler IDs is [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_ID.html).

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use [target_compile_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html) along with [generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#manual:cmake-generator-expressions(7)).
For ex.

```
add_library(foo foo.cpp)
target_compile_options(foo
    PRIVATE
        $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/W3>
        $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:Clang>:-Wall>
        $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:GNU>:-Wall>
)
```

Comment: Typo: ',' -> ':'