# Detect accidental elided dimension in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, static-analysis

Consider the following snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int a[10][2];
int b[10][2];

int main(){

  //intended
  cout << a[0][0] - b[0][0] << endl;

  //left out dimension by mistake
  cout << a[0] - b[0] << endl;

}
```

Obviously (or maybe not per comments) the second case is valid pointer arithmetic in both C and C++ but in the code base I am working with it is generally a semantic mistake; a dimension has usually been left out in a nested for loop.  Is there any -W flag or static analysis tool that can detect this?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, only arithmetic between related pointers is defined behavior. The "pointers" `a[0]` and `b[0]` are not really related, so it's most definitely undefined behavior IMO.

Comment: You could rig up your compiler to print out the parse tree and check if any arithmetic expressions involve operands of pointer type. Clang might make this easy, no idea.

Comment: Ah, in light of Joachims astute observation, try Clang's UBSan.

Comment: @KerrekSB Well, I could be wrong (it's been known to happen!). I just have a recollection of reading it somewhere "official". :)

Comment: Interesting as I have only tried gcc so far with the enormous set of warning flags listed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399850/best-compiler-warning-level-for-c-c-compilers I'll give clang a shot. We don't normally use it here.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: you are right. The relevant clause is 5.7 [expr.add] paragraph 6.

Comment: @frankc: You can use clang for the static analysis and the useful error messages, and GCC for the well-generated code :-)

Comment: Random though: use regular expressions to match `anything[number] operation anything[number]`?

Comment: I tried clang++ with -fsanitize=undefined, as well as -Wall -pedantic and there were no warnings on this test code. It's an older version of clang though in my repo (2.8) so i might need to try a newer one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `std::array` which will not allow that:

```
    using d1=std::array<int, 2>;
    using d2=std::array<d1, 10>;

    d2 a;
    d2 b;

    std::cout << a[0][0] - b[0][0] << endl;  // works as expected

    std::cout << a[0] - b[0] << endl;        // will not compile
```

Comment: I tried this and it fails to compile as expected. I would actually prefer something that has warnings on existing unchanged code, but so far nothing I have tried to do that so this is the best answer

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use a specialized multidimensional array library with appropriate operator error handling, such as boost::multi_array (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html). This is usually a better idea then using nested containers or POD arrays.

Answer (score 2):

If this is only concern for << operator as in example, overload of operator << for int* might help - you can overload operator to generate compile-time error.

Comment: Unfortunately that was just a way for me to show this example in a small snippet. In reality, it's much more insiduious, littered along a bunch of if statements in a huge piece of scientific code. Good thought, though.